# Edit Current Command in Zsh Vi Mode

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, vim, zsh

So I know that you can set vi mode in bash with

`set -o vi`

I also know that you can set vi mode in zsh with

`bindkey -v`

The vi mode in bash has a great feature that allows you to edit the command you are currently working on in the full-out vim editor by pressing `v`.

Is there a way to edit the command like this in zsh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
autoload edit-command-line
zle -N edit-command-line
bindkey -M vicmd v edit-command-line
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much!